# CSS Menu Upwards?

Tags: css, menu, drop-down-menu

I got this from a tutorial website, and was modifying it for my website.

I was wondering if anyone could help me get this CSS menu code to roll out the menu upwards instead of the downwards it goes right now.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background:#F0F0F0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000;
}
#menu {
   clear: both;
   float: left;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
   width: 100%;
   font-size: 90%;
   z-index: 1000;
   position: relative;
}
#menu ul {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
   float: right;
   position: relative;
   right: 50%;
}
#menu ul li {
   margin: 0 0 0 1px;
   padding: 0;
   float: left;
   position: relative;
   left: 50%;
   top: 1px;
}
#menu ul li a {
   display: block;
   margin: 0;
   padding: .6em .5em .4em;
   font-size: 1em;
   line-height: 1em;
   background: #ddd;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #444;
   font-weight: bold;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
#menu ul li.active a {
   color: #fff;
   background: #000;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
   background: #36f;
   color: #fff;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #03f;
}
#menu ul li:hover a,
#menu ul li.hover a {
   background: #36f;
   color: #fff;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #03f;
}
#menu ul ul {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   top: 2em;
   left: 0;
   right: auto;
   width: 10em;
}
#menu ul ul li {
   left: auto;
   margin: 0;
   clear: left;
   width: 100%;
}
#menu ul ul li a,
#menu ul li.active li a,
#menu ul li:hover ul li a {
   font-size: .8em;
   font-weight: normal;
   background: #eee;
   color: #444;
   line-height: 1.4em;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
#menu ul ul li a:hover,
#menu ul li.active ul li a:hover,
#menu ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
   background: #36f;
   color: #fff;
}
#menu ul ul.last {
   left: auto;
   right: 0;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul {
   display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div id="menu">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Tab one</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link one</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link four</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link five</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#" class="active">Tab two</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link one</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link four</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link five is a long link that wraps</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Long tab three</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link one</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link four</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link five</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab four</a>
         <ul class="last">
            <li><a href="#">Link one</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link four</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link five</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a simple solution could be to remove `top` of `#menu ul ul` and add `bottom:2.2em`

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/QMaAu/1

Comment: @SetuShah yes. Or you can remove `top:-10em` and add `bottom:2.2em` which is much better solution. Of course you can change the value to anything that fits your needs

Comment: Thanks for the help :). It appears just the way I want it to :D.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the position of menus above their parent using some js?
check items in menu, set position = parent position - (item height * item count)

Comment: I have no clue on JS. I would prefer some more detailed help then.

I don't mind implementing JS at all.